# Set property of property of property using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

**Assume** we have a class `structure`:

```
class Street {
    String name;
    List<Building> buildings;
}

class Building {
    String number;
    int floors;
    List<Apartment> apartments;
}

class Apartment {
    String owner;
}
```

**I know nothing about the structure above** in `runtime`. All I have is an `object` and a `String` parameter containing data about what properties I have to assign.

For example String `"buildings.0/floors#5"` means I have to assign the floors property of the first Building in the list to 5. And String `"buildings.0/apartments.1/owner#Luke"` means I have to assign to "Luke" the owner property of the second Apartment in the list of apartments of the first Building.

I know how to assign a property using reflection. But what if we have to assign property of the property which is a class itself? Is it possible to implement the logic like this?

Comment: That's doesn't seems to needs reflection. You need to use the index on the specific list. But i am not sure I understand your problem. Could you format your example ? That is a basic integration process based on a String

Comment: I don't know in advance nothing about the list, indexes, fields. How could I possibly set specific property of the object that is placed in the list of properties of some object, just when I don't know anything about this structure?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear about the part not needing reflection... You problem here, is not about reflection, it is how to read this information. You seems to have a pattern here. `listName.index/variable#value`. Each block are separated by `/`. If the result contains `.` this is a list, if it contains `#` this is a variable. left value is the name, right value is the value/index. Just split the string and read from left to right. The only need for reflection is with the name of the instance.

Comment: I just can't understand how to implement it. Well, I get the field of the first object. There's some second object assigned to this field. How would I get fields of this second object?

Comment: Well, with reflection ? Could you post some usage you have in Reflection ? At least showing you have this working so I can write an answer to show you

Comment: It is still a concept. The task requires universal tool to assign properties of unknown structures. It can be something different from reflection... It seemed the only way to me that if I don't know anything about the object structure in runtime, I should look up into code.

Comment: If you only have a concept, there is not much we can do. A **universal** solution would be a real overkill, if not impossible here. Also keep in mind that reflection **is very expensive** in terms of performance and there won't be much opportunities to make up for that. Better create a substantial concept and think of a good design for that, **universial** is a term that often lead to catastrophic results in software development in the past...

Comment: @thatguy This is not that hard to do. Yes there is a lot of risk if this is a API that would be shared but on a controled environnement, this would be usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes respect the JavaBeans convention (standard getters and setters encapsulate fields), you can use the [**`Introspector`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html), and several frameworks that rely on it.

My favorite example would be [Spring's BeanWrapper technology](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beans-conventions), which allows you to write code like this:

```
BeanWrapper bw = new BeanWrapperImpl(street);
bw.setPropertyValue("buildings[0].appartments[1].owner", "luke");
```

Comment: Thank you, it is really useful!

Answer (score 1):

I have just do a simply solution based on your Structure. This have a lot to be add (NullPointerException, OutOfBounds, ...) but for correct input, you have a correct answer.

Then you just need to methods, one to set a value, one to get a instance from a list. Both need to use reflection.

```
public Object getListItem(Object o, String name, int index) throws Exception{
    return ((List)o.getClass().getDeclaredField(name).get(o)).get(index);
}

public void setValue(Object o, String name, Object value) throws Exception{
    o.getClass().getDeclaredField(name).set(o, value);
}
```

Like a said, no checks are made, I did simple since I do that from scratch.

Then, just need to parse the String (again, no check) based on `/` to find each [variable/value] blocs. And find what type this is :

- if it contains `#`, this is an attribution
- if it contains `.`, this is a getter in a list

So this should looks like this.

```
public void init(Object o, String pattern) throws Exception{
    String[] array = pattern.split("/");
    for(String s : array){
        if(s.contains("#")){
            String[] param = s.split("\\#");
            setValue(o, param[0], param[1]);
        } else {
            String[] list = s.split("\\.");
            o = getListItem(o, list[0], Integer.parseInt(list[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the output from the example you can find on ideone [here](http://ideone.com/WOQsXC)

That will output

```
[Street] Foo [
        [Building] 1 1[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null], 
        [Building] 2 2[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null, [Apartment] null, [Apartment] null], 
        [Building] 3 1[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null]]
[Street] Foo [
        [Building] 1 1[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null], 
        [Building] 2 3[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null, [Apartment] null, [Apartment] null], 
        [Building] 3 1[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null]]
[Street] Foo [
        [Building] 1 1[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null], 
        [Building] 2 3[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] null, [Apartment] null, [Apartment] null], 
        [Building] 3 1[[Apartment] null, [Apartment] John]]
```

Comment: This is done in 10lines without any checks but since I have done a lot without example, sorry for this long post. PS : You are lucky I am bored, you gave nothing so I should have skipped this question ;)